# middah k'neged middah by Purim?

Tags: purim

Of course the concept of V'nehapichu is most spoken about during Purim, but what about middah k'neged middah?

Where can i find some literature and commentary about how this was included in the miracle?

Comment: Well you have haman getting hung on his own tree as a clear example

Comment: Yes, where can i find commentaries that call that middah k'neged middah? Usually, with regard to purim, it all gets bunched together into the concept of V'nehapchu.

Comment: מדה כנגד מדה is just a tit-for-tat style of punishment. ונהפוך הוא is much greater; it represents the transformation of evil to good.

Comment: @shmosel Thanks, is that mentioned anywhere or is this your own pshat?

Comment: I don't have a specific source, but I don't think it's my invention.